# application execution, java related

Tags: windows, java

We are having an issue with apllication that is affecting multiple users. We have prepared fresh packages for their laptops. But for some of them the application will not run giving Java errors, with main being: "java.lang.exceptioninitializererror: null".

Now what I cannot figure out is that we have deployed their PC using same template of images so they all have same Java installed 6.31.

Another thing is that If myself (I am working in IT) run this app form their PC, so its basically the same environment, same java etc. (run as different user...) it runs!

I have tried reinstalling, using different java versions, but nothing seem to work. We are not sure where the problem might be located/

If need be I can upload very long java error.

---

what i've found is that the app doesnt really start with exe file but instead users use .bat file to start it:

---

@echo off
setlocal
set vis_host=**********
set vis_port=*********
cd .\java\jre\bin

javaws.exe -userConfig deployment.javaws.autodownload "ALWAYS"
javaws.exe http://***************************

### cd ...... @echo on

is it possible that somehow above cannot be executued due to incorrect java settings?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions problem.

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine what resource(s) the application is trying to access (and being denied) so that you can adjust the permissions granted to the user.